# Get NullPointerException when calling getSystemService()

Tags: android, android-activity, nullpointerexception

My problem is, that in onCreate() method of my MainActivity I am creating new Thread object to which I want to pass reference to `this` activity, and than in that thread use it to call getSystemService(). But in the end, when I start the app it crashes and I get NullPointerException.

I have already found that problem could be that I am passing reference to activity befor super.onCreate(), but in my code super.onCreate() is performed before passing the reference.

This is my MainActivity's onCreate() method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Instance which contains thread for obtaining wifi info
    final WifiInfoThread wifi_info = new WifiInfoThread(this);
....
}
```

And this is Thread class in which I am trying to get reference to system service

```
public class WifiInfoThread extends Thread {
// Constructor for passing context to this class to be able to access xml resources
Activity activity;
WifiInfoThread(Activity current) {
    activity = current;
}

// Flag for stopping thread
boolean flag = false;
// Obtain service and WifiManager object
WifiManager current_wifi = (WifiManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

// Runnable object passed to UIThread
Runnable uirunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Get current wifi status
        WifiInfo wifi_info = current_wifi.getConnectionInfo();

        // Things with showing it on screen
        TextView tv_output = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.tv_output);
        String info = "SSID: " + wifi_info.getSSID();
        info += "\nSpeed: " + wifi_info.getLinkSpeed() + " Mbps";
        tv_output.setText(info);
    }
};

public void run() {
    flag = true;

    for(; flag; ) {
        activity.runOnUiThread(uirunnable);
        try {
            this.sleep(500);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Dear downvoter, the user has just now created an account and asked a question, don't be hasty in downvoting. Perhaps an edit or a comment would be warmer welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `activity.getSystemService` before initializing `activity`. To get ride of this, move below line into `Constructor`

```
// Obtain service and WifiManager object
WifiManager current_wifi = (WifiManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

Like

```
WifiManager current_wifi;
WifiInfoThread(Activity current) {
    activity = current;
    current_wifi = (WifiManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

move the initialitation `current_wifi` in the `Constructor` of your Thread.

```
// Obtain service and WifiManager object
WifiManager current_wifi = (WifiManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

in your case, `activity` is still a `null` reference. It gets a valid one after you assign it in the constructor

Answer (score 0):

The other answers show you how to fix this. You should also know *what* is the reason for the `NullPointerException`: In java your code does not get executed in the order you write it. Every thing written outside of member functions (methods) gets executed first (sort of). Then the constructor is called. Hence you are calling  `Conetxt.getSystemService()` on `activity`, which is `null`.

Also for background work, android has `AsyncTask` and `IntentService`. Look them up.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, and also for advice, I've been looking for those things for quite a long time

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!